# Transfer a row in a csv (for eg) into a actually row name

Tags: c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amjsd.png)

In this picture you can see the first row 1 dmin_mu etc...

I want this as my rownames and not in my actual data.

Programm: R-Studio but also R 3.3.3.

Comment: Please edit your post with the **text** of your relevant code, not links to images.  Images may not be viewable on all displays; text is.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `std::string` and `std::getline`.

```
std::string first_row;
std::getline(my_data, first_row);
std::string column_header1, column_header2, column_header3, column_header4;
my_data >> column_header1 >> column_header2 >> column_header3 >> column_header4;
```

Were you looking for something different?

Comment: Thank you. And thx for the -1 (idk why? Im totally new here). Ill try this.What do you mean with different?

Comment: Ok now i have this. Now i want to sort my table and add a column with a function but it dont works. My table looks horrible and i want it looks like a normal table with the columns are in the middle not right or left orietated.